# Tomcat Server does not start from the command line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I used Eclipse EE luna. I couldn't start the tomcat7 server from inside eclipse while i can start it from cmd.It gave `Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.` error.I tried all the answers here but none of them helped me. Then i deleted my eclipse EE luna and downloaded juno package.

Here is the problem : This time i can start tomcat server from inside the eclipse and everything works fine, however, after stopping server from eclipse, i can't start it from cmd(My opinion is startup.bat thinks that server is still running and cancels the process).Therefore I can't deploy my projects under `\tomcat7path\webapps\`, just running it from eclipse.(It also runs from web browser. Actually this is an another question. How can it run from browser while "myproject" doesn't exist under `\tomcat7path\webapps\` directory.)

I am stuck on this, any help would be appreciated.

More informaton: I am developing servlets using eclipse ee juno, on tomcat-7.0.55

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: it is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException as i understand.(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solved the problem, finally. I removed `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` environment variables, then opened a new command line window and started tomcat. It gave "`Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined.At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program`" error.
After redefining `JAVA_HOME`, i started a new cmd and tried again. This time it worked.